# Task priorities in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, todo

I know two ways to create tasks using Eclipse; with the tasks view or with the `TODO` annotation in a comment:

```
//TODO: wtf? Rewrite it using constants.
int foo = 3.1 * 3;
```

If I use the first way, I can edit tasks and set the "priority".

Can I do it for tasks that I create using `TODO` annotation?

Comment: What second way are you talking about? please clarify

Comment: @thejh, updated. I mean, "if i create  task with todo annotation (as in example) could I define it's priority?"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I know that with `FIXME` priority is set to High, while with `TODO` is set to Normal.
This is configurable too: inside Window > Properties search for "Task tags".

Comment: This thread is quite old, but I'd like to mention also the XXX Tag. It has nothing to do with porn, but marks a code like a TODO with a lower priority. This means a XXX mark is a TODO you "could" do someday, or just an idea you don't want to forget. TODOs you "should" do, and FIXMEs you "must" do. Just my 2 cents here.

Comment: @Asturio interesting usage, anyway low priority for XXX needs to be set in Properties, because by default it has normal priority.

Answer (score 11):

Go to File > Properties > Task Tags

```
By default TODO = normal priority
           FIXME = high priority
```

You can specify new priority labels and give them normal, low, or high priorities. (you might need to click on 'enable project specific settings').

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Task` Tags and make XXX as a high priority alias of `FIXME`. These high priority tags are used for items that should be looked at before the next release while the normal `TODO` tags are used to mark items that aren't critical.

Source: http://www.newt.com/java/eclipse/